# Coping good from web-sites.(django)

Tags: django

Oh,hello there! I am now writing a site, where I need to copy the goods from another web-site. Is there any idea of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean with "*copy the goods fron (sic.) another web-site (sic.)*"

Comment: means some web-store has things to buy online and i need to copy them on my site